Add "Printable version" to Mediawiki Navigation menu
I am trying to add the "Printable version" option below "Random page"
I have tried editing the MediaWiki:Sidebar (see below) but I could not find an option that worked.
* navigation
** mainpage|mainpage-description
** recentchanges-url|recentchanges
** randompage-url|randompage
* SEARCH
* TOOLBOX

Using MediaWiki 1.39, Timeless theme
https://ibb.co/yVtG4fy

Try this: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Seb35/modifyToolbox.

Thanks, I tried adding it to LocalSettings.php and adding this in MediaWiki:Sidebar ** PRINT|printableversion but the result was to go to a page called "print", not the print function.
